# Creating SQL statements programmatically using Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, tapestry, jdbctemplate

I need to create SQL statement programmatically. I have values in map in form *<"column_name",value>*. Now I have a base query, I add a where clause and as iterating through the map, if the value is not null I add this *" " + key + "=" + value + " and "*. Then I cut he last 5 characters and it's done. I would like to use something better than this. Note that I'm using Tapestry 5 + Spring JDBC Template (Hibernate is not an option).

Thanks, Ondrej

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use dynamic condition I still recommend to generate `where` with `?` like

```
" " + key + "=?"
```

and then iterate again to call `preparedStatement.setXXX`. Depending on the driver you can call `setObject` or check parameter type:

```
if (value instanceof String) 
    preparedStatement.setString((String)value)
else if ...
```

Using `?` have it's advantages:

- You don't think about converting types like `Date` to string and quoting of special symbols.
- Database can cache execution plans more effectively when you use `?` and not literal values.

Comment: Yes, but how would I create the PreparedStatement? I'm using JDBCTemplate, so I have no connection to create the statement on.

Comment: @Ondrej: If you use JDBCTemplate, you need to pass arguments as an array rather than setting them individually.

Comment: You have `query(String sql, Object[] args, RowMapper rowMapper) ` where you can pass values as `args` provided you already have `sql` with `?`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for simething like [squiggle-sql](http://code.google.com/p/squiggle-sql/). 
And do not forget about prepared statements with it's 'set' methods.

Comment: Is seems pretty nice, but is it stable and tested? The last build is from 2009 for java 1.4, which isn't very new.

Comment: That's true, not much activity there. But, it's quite small and simple, so I do not expect to have any any problems with it. I would even suggest to copy sources into the project and use them directly and extend if required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the class PreparedStatementCreator

```
final String INSERT_SQL = "insert into my_test (name) values(?)";
final String name = "Rob";

KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
jdbcTemplate.update(
    new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps =
                connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL, new String[] {"id"});
            ps.setString(1, name);
            return ps;
        }
    },
    keyHolder);

// keyHolder.getKey() now contains the generated key
```

Reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html

See section: 11.2.8